# R Shiny: How To Create A Remove Button

Tags: r, shiny

What I have learnt from the differences between the ADD and REMOVE Button.

As we can see from the codes below, the main difference is how the ADD and REMOVE buttons affect the ***scenarios*** line. The REMOVE button effectively uses the `scenarios[-length(scenarios)]` command to remove the immediate last ***scenario*** while keeping the other codes constant with the ADD button.

A very simple one-line code solution, and yet elegant approach to solve the problem. I learned alot again. Thank you all.

```
observeEvent(input$add, {
if (!(shock %in% scenarios)) {
      scenarios <<- sort(c(scenarios, shock))
      updateCheckboxGroupInput(session, "scenarios",choices = scenarios,selected = scenarios)
    }

  observeEvent(input$remove,{
    scenarios <<- scenarios[-length(scenarios)]
    updateCheckboxGroupInput(session, "scenarios",choices = scenarios,selected = scenarios)
  })
```

Comment: Hi Chen! This sounds to me like a homework question, so I'll attempt to guide you towards the answer without giving it to you outright: you declare the `remove` button in the `ui`, but never use it in the `server`. Where should you use it? The `add` input is inside an `observeEvent` to be reactive. So the `remove` also should be reactive, right?

Comment: I see. =/ We've all had our share of bad teachers, so I completely understand. I find that the [tutorials from the Rstudio team](https://shiny.rstudio.com/tutorial/) are quite helpful and follow a logical progression. You'll see that you need to grasp one concept at a time and that will allow you to tackle anything you need. The goal is not to answer specific questions, but to learn the tools to figure it out. :) You can always ask homework questions here, and as long as you show that you have given the problem real thought and attempted a solution yourself, people will help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do:

```
library(shiny)
ui <- fluidPage(
  numericInput("shock", "Shock", value = round(runif(1) * 1000), 0),
  actionButton("add", "Add"),
  actionButton("remove", "Remove"),
  checkboxGroupInput("scenarios", "Scenarios", choices = c(), selected = c()),
  verbatimTextOutput("o1")
)
scenarios <- c(-100, -50, 0, 50, 100)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  updateCheckboxGroupInput(session, "scenarios",
                           choices = scenarios,
                           selected = scenarios)

  observeEvent(input$add,{

    shock <- isolate(input$shock)

    if (!(shock %in% scenarios)) {
      scenarios <<- sort(c(scenarios, shock))
      updateCheckboxGroupInput(session, "scenarios",choices = scenarios,selected = scenarios)
    }
    # put a new random value
    updateNumericInput(session, "shock", value = round(runif(1) * 1000))
  })

  observeEvent(input$remove,{
    scenarios <<- scenarios[-length(scenarios)]
    updateCheckboxGroupInput(session, "scenarios",choices = scenarios,selected = scenarios)
  })

  output$o1 <- renderPrint({
    x <- input$scenarios
    str(x)
    cat(paste0("length: ", length(x), "\n"))
    cat(paste0(x, "\n"))
  })
}
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

[image]

Comment: Hi, I just wanted to make you aware of the [discussion on SO when it comes to questions like this on Meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/334823/8485403). If you could edit your answer and provide some explanations, that would be helpful. Thanks ;)

Comment: Dear Pork Chop, thank you so much for your kind help. I was wondering would it be much harder for the REMOVE button to remove specific data that is keyed into the Shock Box. For example, if 31 is keyed, then the REMOVE button searches for 31 and removes it if it can be found. Otherwise it shows an error message  "31 cannot be found". Secondly, do you have any suggestion where I can learn Shiny online for free? Thank you for your time.